# How can I play a sound through python regardless of file location?

Tags: python, audio, path

I'm trying to play music through python:

```
import winsound

winsound.PlaySound("A", winsound.SND_FILENAME)
winsound.PlaySound("C", winsound.SND_FILENAME)
winsound.PlaySound("D", winsound.SND_FILENAME)
winsound.PlaySound("D", winsound.SND_FILENAME)
```

which works, but only while the python file is in the same folder as the sounds. Can I get it to play the sounds from anywhere? Or how do I properly import the sound from a specific path without the python file being with the sound files?

I tried:

```
   winsound.PlaySound("C:\Users\User_Name\Desktop\Microbit\A", 
   winsound.SND_FILENAME)
```

I haven't done any coding in a while and I can't remember how to import things properly.

Comment: What are your sound files actually called? If `winsound.PlaySound("A", winsound.SND_FILENAME)` works, that suggests the file is called `A` (with no extension, but perhaps an extension is assumed by `winsound`. Providing the full filename and path to a file in a format supported by `winsound` should work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not familiar with the windsound library, but you usually need to escape the '\'.
I imagine you also need the file type on the end of your string(.mp3, etc.)
try:

```py
winsound.PlaySound("C:\\Users\\User_Name\\Desktop\\Microbit\\A.file_type", #.mp3, .wav, etc
winsound.SND_FILENAME)
```

Comment: Thanks that worked. For some reason the double slashes fixed it. Never had to use them before though.